# Why is the following statement true in a proof that I'm studying on binary search trees?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, trees

I was studying a proof and there was this line:

$\sum_n^h2^n = 1+2+4+ ... +2^{h-1} + 2^{h} = 2^{h+1} -1$
where (n = 0,1,2,...)

It's been a while since I studied series, can someone help me understand why this is the case? I checked with input and it worked. 
Are they using some property of series or is it something totally obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note the following pattern of the sum: $1+2+4+… 2^{h-1}+2^h$.

One can easily see that the successive terms are multiplied by $2$, the common ratio. Thus, the series is a [finite geometric progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)  with common ratio $r =2$ and starting term $a=1$.

Comment: @V.Poghosyan You can accept my answer if it helped you by ticking the green mark on the side.

Comment: Ah! 
So the sum is 1*(2^h-1)/(2-1) = 2^h - 1. 
I still don't understand why it's 2^(h+1) - 1. I checked the starting and ending points.

Comment: Note that $2^h$ is the $(n+1)$th term. So, you have to use the geometric series summing n+1 terms. So, $2^h-1 + 2^h = 2(2^h) -1 =2^{h+1}-1$!

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
\eqalign{
S &= 1 + 2 + 4 + \cdots + 2^h \cr
2S &= 2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots + 2^{h+1} \cr
}
$$
substracting from the second the first we get
$$
S = 2^{h+1} - 1
$$